# cmake error: attempt to add link library

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, as starting point to work with Moveit and my custom robot i downloaded and modified

```
xxx://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2
```

i put the folder in my catkin workspace under /src, renamed everything according to my robot and used a lot of examples.

Now i need to launch some original pr2 tutorial so i downloaded same package again this time i left everything intact but when i launch catkin_make i get lot's linking errors like this one:

> CMake Error at moveit_pr2-hydro-devel/pr2_moveit_tutorials/planning/CMakeLists.txt:18 (target_link_libraries):
> Attempt to add link library "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libimage_transport.so" to
> target "move_group_interface_tutorial" which is not built in this
> directory.

If I delete the modified package version I use with my custom robot everything compile fine but then i can't launch the examples anymore.
If I launch

```
rospack find pr2_moveit_tutorials
```

I see correctly:

> /home/gabri/catkin_ws/src/moveit_pr2-hydro-devel/pr2_moveit_tutorials

but when I launch the tutorial with:

```
roslaunch pr2_moveit_tutorials motion_planning_interface_tutorial.launch
```

I get this error:

> [motion_planning_interface_tutorial.launch] is neither a launch file in package [pr2_moveit_tutorials] nor is [pr2_moveit_tutorials] a launch file name

What am I missing?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186135/cmake-error:-attempt-to-add-link-library/) by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When installing from source, be sure that all the dependencies it requires are either installed in your ROS ecosystem or are also being compiled from source.

When trying to use programs installed by source, you'll also have to source that workspace by

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

And when wanting to specify something installed in the ROS ecosystem at /opt/ros/hydro/*

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

Cheers,
Devon

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on 2014-07-14**:
Thank you, actually the second problem was caused just by a mispelling, the launch file mentioned in the tutorial "Motion Planners/C++ API" has a different name in the pr_2_moveit_tutorials package. real launch file is: motion_planning_api_tutorial.launch.

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-14**:
Great! Could you please file an issue so that this can be patched in the future? I would greatly appreciate your support :D

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2

Is this ticket solved now?

**Comment by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on 2014-07-17**:
issue created, yes it is solved. Thank you for your support.
G.